# How to obtain Apache mod_jk connector for for RHL?

Tags: apache, tomcat, connector, mod-jk

I am looking for a mod_jk.so for Apache 2.4.6 on RHEL linux, could not find anywhere. Tried to build from source that did not go through as well. Any one knows the correct location to download or any worked solution to build?

thanks 
Vasu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is step by step installation of mod_jk

```
# mkdir mod-jk

# wget http://www.eu.apache.org/dist/tomcat/tomcat-connectors/jk/tomcat-connectors-1.2.41-src.tar.gz

# tar -xf tomcat-connectors-1.2.41-src.tar.gz

# yum install -y httpd-devel gcc gcc-c++ make libtool
# cd tomcat-connectors-1.2.41-src/native
# ./configure --with-apxs=/usr/sbin/apxs
# make
# libtool --finish /usr/lib64/httpd/modules
# make install
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the response, it worked well, only thing that was different for me was the apxs location. After changing that form /ust/sbin/apxs to /ust/bin/apxs it went well. thank you.