# Load balancing workers will not function properly

Tags: tomcat, mod-jk

Please refer this question: [Centos With Plesk11.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33551523/centos-with-plesk11-x)

I did same configuration on another VPS but with no luck. 
Log says:
errno=13. Load balancing workers will not function properly

Please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disable SELINUX to fix this problem

```
set enforce 0
```

and then follow these steps

```
yum -y install policycoreutils-python
semanage fcontext -a -t httpd_var_run_t "/var/run/mod_jk(/.*)?"
service httpd restart
```

Comment: Thanks A Lot. Its Working